# Insert a label automatically in products obtained through web scraping

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping, label, rvest

Goodmorning everyone . I'm a newbie. I'm doing web scraping tests.
I have a column with the article number (EAN). For each of them I find certain products.

```
EAN
4895142606403
8714574564333
4960999357256
4895142611315


for (i in seq_along(EAN) ) { 
  
  url_reviews <- paste0("https://www.ebay.it/sch/i.html_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw=",EAN[i,],"&_sacat=0")

  doc <- read_html(url_reviews) # pagina risultato

  name <- data.frame(doc %>% html_nodes(".s-item__title") %>% html_text())

  colnames(name) <- "title
}
```

would like to have two columns, one with the products found and the other containing the respective
EAN code. Basically I would like the EAN code to repeat in the side column for each product.
Something like that.

```
    EAN         TITLE
5706991018127   ⭐JABRA STEALTH UC AURICOLARE BLUETOOTH [233969]
5706991018127   JABRA Cuffia Bluetooth con Microfono Auricolare Wireless 5578-230-109 Stealt UC
5706991018127   Cuffia Pc 5578-230-109 Jabra Stealth Uc Cuffie Con Microfono In-Ear Wireless Blu
5706991018127   NUOVO! Stealth Jabra UC Cuffie Bluetooth REGNO UNITO PC/mobile in
4960999357256   CARTUCCIA ORIGINALE CANON 1038B001 PGI-9PC PHOTO CYAN PIXMA PRO9500 PRO 9500
4960999357256   Cartuccia Originale Inkjet colore Ciano Canon 1038B001
4960999357256   Canon PGI-9PC Photo cyan original ink tank for PIXMA Pro9500 Pro9500 1038B001
```

How can I do ? thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Write a function which returns a dataframe with EAN number and reviews.

```
library(rvest)

get_review <- function(EAN, page_num){
  url_reviews <- paste0("https://www.ebay.it/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=",EAN,"&_sacat=0&_pgn=", page_num)
  doc <- read_html(url_reviews) # pagina risultato
  data.frame(EAN = EAN, 
             title = doc %>% html_nodes(".s-item__title") %>% html_text())
}
```

You can use `map_df` to call this function for each `EAN` number. If your dataframe is called `df` and column as `EAN` do :

```
library(purrr)
result <- map_df(1:2, function(i) map_df(df$EAN, ~get_review(.x, i)))
```

Comment: @ Ronak Shah  Thank you so much for your help, but I get this error message.                                        Error: Can't convert a `data.frame` object to function

Comment: @StefanoMariaDeFrancesco What is the dataframe called where you have `EAN` numbers? I have assumed it is `df` hence I have used `df$EAN`, if it is called something else use that instead of `df`.

Comment: @ Ronak Shah Yes sure. However, the problem changes when I also insert the page number in the URL.      url_reviews <- paste0("https://www.ebay.it/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=",EAN,"&_sacat=0&_pgn=", page_num)                                     Now I couldn't leave the blank in the EAN field of the get_review function and just fill in the blank of page_num because it would give me an error immediately.  
result <- purrr::map_df(df$EAN, get_review(, 1:2))    How can I change it? Thanks in advance for your time and advice

Comment: Check if the updated answer helps? @StefanoMariaDeFrancesco

Comment: @ Ronak Shah Perfect. If you ever happen to pass through Rome then write me because you will have a complete (Italian) lunch paid for by me. Thanks a lot, Ronak!

Comment: Haha..thank you , that's very kind of you. :)